# ncurses: handle keyboard inputs in the terminal in C++

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to build a simple tetris game within the terminal. I need to move the pieces when the player presses an arrow key. I heard about the getch() method but it doesn't seem to work with arrow keys (they were all detected with the same int code: 27). What should I do?

Here is my current code:

```cpp
    initscr();
    int inputCode;
    do
    {
        inputCode = getch();
        // here I would put my code to move the pieces if the code is right
    } while (inputCode != 113); // q to exit
    endwin();
```

Sincerely,
Thomas

Comment: You can always use wasd

Comment: `getch()` should return `KEY_UP`, `KEY_DOWN`, `KEY_LEFT` or `KEY_RIGHT` when pressed.  Try adding calls to `raw(); keypad(stdscr, TRUE); noecho();` before your loop.

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [NCURSES- Arrow keys not detected?](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/248599/), [11. Interfacing with the key board](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The as noted in the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization):

```
   Most programs would additionally use the sequence:

       intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
       keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

That is, your program should turn on [keypad](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) mode to get `KEY_UP`, etc:

> The  keypad  option  enables the keypad of the user's terminal.  If enabled (bf is TRUE), the user can press a function key (such as an arrow
> key)  and  wgetch(3x)  returns a single value representing the function
> key, as in KEY_LEFT.  If disabled (bf is FALSE), curses does not  treat
> function keys specially and the program has to interpret the escape sequences itself.  If the keypad in the terminal can be turned  on  (made
> to  transmit)  and  off  (made to work locally), turning on this option
> causes the terminal keypad to be turned on when wgetch(3x)  is  called.
> The default value for keypad is FALSE.